# Do multiple copies of a building all trigger in Megaland

Tags: megaland

In Red Raven Games' Megaland, if you have multiple copies of a trigger building do they all activate when their condition is met or do you only get one activation per building type?

So if I have three copies of Temple of Zoz

> 2 Coins when you meet the red serpent

Do I get 2 coins or 6 coins when the red serpent shows up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Megaland Page from Red Raven Games](https://redravengames.squarespace.com/megaland) has both free rules PDF and a clarifications PDF. The clarifications PDF states:

> **Building Stacking**
> Every building’s abilities stack except for the Soap Maker’s. All buildings of the same type trigger simultaneously.

So, in your example, if you were to run across or jump over the Red Serpent you would gain 6 coins; 2 coins per Temple of Zoz card you own (3).